# extend class default value of parent parameter

Tags: kotlin, constructor, instance, instantiation, default-parameters

I have class `B` with to parameters `x` and `y` extended from class `A` with parameter `x` which is optional (all parmaters are non-null) how can I define `B` in a way that it would be optional and it would use the optional value in constructor of `A`

```
val y = 0
val b = if (y == 0) B(y) else B(y, 0)

class B(y: Int, x: Int = 238) : A(x)

open class A(x: Int = 238)
```

here I have set the default value for `x` in constructor of `B` is there any way to achieve this without having to set default value in `B`

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this with secondary constructors.

```
class B : A {
    constructor(y: Int): super()
    constructor(y: Int, x: Int): super(x)
}
```

For more information see [Kotlin Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#inheritance).

Edit:

As @PietroMartinelli mentions the secondary constructors would not work if you need primary constructor. If the derived class has a primary constructor, the base class can (and must) be initialized right there, using the parameters of the primary constructor.

Comment: This approach is not working when you need (or would) to define a not empty primary constructor in the `B` subclass, isn't it?

Comment: @PietroMartinelli That's true. With primary constructor the class has to be initialized right away so this would not work.

Comment: Ok, it's anyway a nice approach, if you don't need a primary constructor ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The approach proposed in the @Januson's answer is very nice and clean when you does not neet/would define a primary constructor in the `B` subclass. If you try to do so, you get compiler errors, because auxiliary constructors must call primary constructor and can't call superclass constructors directly.

If you `B` subclass need to define a primary constructor, you can approach the problem defining the default value as a constant in `A`'s *companion object* and use it in both `A`'s and `B`'s primary constructors, as follows:

```
open class A(val x: Int = DefaultX) {
    companion object {
        val DefaultX:Int = 238;
    }
}

class B(y: Int, x: Int = DefaultX) : A(x)
```

This way you define the equivalent of a Java `static final` variable, scoped to `A`.

You should refer to the superclass' `A.DefaultX` constant in the `B` subclass, but you don't need duplicate its value in both class `A` and class `B`...

Comment: Pietro Martinelli since I have multiple layers of inheritance defining default value as a companian method or field make my code cleaner but performance wise I think @Januson's solution is a little bit more efficient (its not much either way :D) anyways for this one I'm going for cleaner

Comment: @PietroMartinelli I will be grateful have your opinion about my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, something like this maybe help you!

```
val y = 0
val b = if (y == 0) B(y) else B(y, 0)

class B(y: Int, x: Int) : A() {
    constructor(y: Int) : this(y, if (y == 0) 238 else 0)
}

open class A(x: Int = 238)
```

Comment: @Januson I will be grateful have your opinion.